# How to ignore last column in column count? I am using Apache POI to read excel data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I use below piece of code for TC_001, it returns 8 as a column count, but I want the last row to be ignored in counting column which has Comment section. I want column count as 5 as there are 5 column with text ignoring the comment(Action 1) part.

```
int colCount = DataProviderFactory.getExcel().getColCount(0, 1);//this is user defined function using Apache POI to get column count of sheet with index 0 and row 1
```

[image]

So is there any way that on how to get column count ignoring the "Comment" row from count? I guess if there is any way to treat "G" row as last row then it might solve it. So the TC_001 should have count as 5, TC_002 as 7, TC_003 as 4, TC_004 as 1 etc. I tried to search solution online & found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304383/camel-bindy-how-to-ignore-last-columns) one but have no idea how to implement it whether I have to add this in code or in excel or this is something different from my requirement. Please guide me on how I can achieve my requirement.

Comment: Maybe you should include the code for `DataProviderFactory.getExcel().getColCount(0, 1)` as this doesn't look like a apache-poi method to me

Comment: How do you figure there are 5 columns? I do not see what exactly you want ignored there.

Comment: @harmonica141, in row 2 there are 5 out of 7 relevant columns filled with text, in row 3 there are 7 out of 7 etc.

Comment: Does column H always has a value?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer No. H will have value for some row and may not be for other row

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Regarding DataProviderFactory.getExcel().getColCount(0, 1), these are library class and methods inside it which uses Apache POI function. Sorry for the confusion, I should have shown direct function instead using my derived function here

Answer (score 0):

```
row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
```

is what you are looking for. From the documentation of that method:

> Gets the number of defined cells (NOT number of cells in the actual
>   row!). That is to say if only columns 0,4,5 have values then there
>   would be 3.

As you now want to ignore the last column, you can simply do `row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells() - 1;`, given that the comment is **always** filled.

EDIT:

This method should work for columns A to G:

```
private static int getNumOfCellsWithContent(int rowNum, Sheet sheet) {
    int result = 0;
    Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    if (r == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7/* 7 = H */; i++) {
        Cell c = r.getCell(i);
        if (c != null && !c.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.BLANK)) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In my case for some case comment will be filled and for other cases it would be blank also

Comment: I am getting error message on this line if (c != null && !c.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.BLANK)), eclipse giving suggestion to create CellType class, there is nothing to import for CellType. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Make sure you are using a modern enough version of Apache POI

Comment: That code was created with apache poi 3.17. In 4.0.0, `getCellTypeEnum()` needs to be replaced with `getCellType()` afaik

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function to get the value cell excel using Apache poi 3.17, hope this can help.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String excelFile = "/path/Book1.xlsx";

        //check row TC_001
        int rowNumber = 1;

        int columnCount = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            String getCellValue = new Test().getCellDatatable(excelFile, 0, rowNumber, i);
            if(!getCellValue.equals("")) {
                System.out.println(getCellValue);
                columnCount++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("columnCount :" +columnCount);
    }

    public String getCellDatatable(String pathAndDatatableName, int indexSheet, int indexRow, int indexColumn) throws IOException {
        String getString;

        File myDT = new File(pathAndDatatableName);

        FileInputStream myDoc = null;
        myDoc = new FileInputStream(myDT);

        XSSFWorkbook myExcel = null;
        myExcel = new XSSFWorkbook(myDoc);

        XSSFSheet mySheet = myExcel.getSheetAt(indexSheet);

        XSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(indexRow);
        if(row!=null) {
            XSSFCell myGetString = mySheet.getRow(indexRow).getCell(indexColumn);
            getString = getStringByCell(myGetString);
            return getString;
        }else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private String getStringByCell(Cell cell){
        String getStrCell = null;
            if(cell != null) {
                if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                    getStrCell = cell.toString();
                }else if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        getStrCell = dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
                    }else {
                        Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        Long longValue = value.longValue();
                        getStrCell = new String(longValue.toString());
                    }
                }else if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BOOLEAN) {
                    getStrCell = new String(new Boolean(cell.getBooleanCellValue()).toString());
                }else if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK) {
                    getStrCell = "";
                }
            }else {
                getStrCell = "";
            }
        return getStrCell;
    }
}
```